# Find the city with highest number of amenities

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am currently trying to crack a programming puzzle that has the very simple dataframe `host` with 2 columns named `city` and `amenities` (both are `object` datatype). Now, entries in both columns could be repeated multiple times. Below is the first few entries of `host` is beLOW

```
City    Amenities                                            Price($)
NYC    {TV,"Wireless Internet", "Air conditioning","Smoke      8
        detector",Essentials,"Lock on bedroom door"} 
LA     {"Wireless Internet",Kitchen,Washer,Dryer,"First aid    
        kit",Essentials,"Hair dryer","translation missing: 
         en.hosting_amenity_49","translation missing: 
         en.hosting_amenity_50"} 
                                                               10
SF     {TV,"Cable TV",Internet,"Wireless Internet",Kitchen,"Free 
        parking on premises","Pets live on this 
        property",Dog(s),"Indoor fireplace","Buzzer/wireless 
        intercom",Heating,Washer,Dryer,"Smoke detector","Carbon 
        monoxide detector","First aid kit","Safety card","Fire e 
        extinguisher",Essentials,Shampoo,"24-hour check- 
        in",Hangers,"Hair dryer",Iron,"Laptop friendly 
        workspace","translation missing: 
        en.hosting_amenity_49","translation missing: 
        en.hosting_amenity_50","Self Check-In",Lockbox}        15
NYC    {"Wireless Internet","Air 
        conditioning",Kitchen,Heating,"Suitable for events","Smoke 
        detector","Carbon monoxide detector","First aid kit","Fire 
        extinguisher",Essentials,Shampoo,"Lock on bedroom 
        door",Hangers,"translation missing: 
        en.hosting_amenity_49","translation missing: 
        en.hosting_amenity_50"}                                20
LA     {TV,Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air 
        conditioning",Kitchen,"Free parking on 
        premises",Essentials,Shampoo,"translation missing: 
        en.hosting_amenity_49","translation missing: 
        en.hosting_amenity_50"}
LA    {TV,"Cable TV",Internet,"Wireless Internet",Pool,Kitchen,"Free 
       parking on premises",Gym,Breakfast,"Hot tub","Indoor 
       fireplace",Heating,"Family/kid friendly",Washer,Dryer,"Smoke 
       detector","Carbon monoxide detector",Essentials,Shampoo,"Lock 
       on bedroom door",Hangers,"Private entrance"}           28

.....
```

**Question.** Output the city with the highest number of amenities.

**My attempt.** I tried using `groupby()` function to group it based on column `city` using `host.groupby('city').` Now, I need to **count** successfully the number of elements in each set of Amenities. Since the data types are different, the `len()` function did not work because there are `\` between each element in the set (for example, if I use `host['amenities'][0],` the output is `"{TV,\"Wireless Internet\",\"Air conditioning\",\"Smoke detector\",\"Carbon monoxide detector\",Essentials,\"Lock on bedroom door\",Hangers,Iron}"`. Applying `len()` to this output would result in **134**, which is clearly incorrect). I tried using `host['amenities'][0].strip('\n')` which removes the `\,` but the `len()` function still gives `134.`

Can anyone please help me crack this problem?

**My solution, inspired by ddejohn's solution:**

```
### Transform each "string-type" entry in column "amenities" to "list" type
host["amenities"] = host["amenities"].str.replace('["{}]', "", regex=True).str.split(",")

## Create a new column that count all the amenities for each row 
entry host["am_count"] = [len(data) for data in host["amenities"]]

## Output the index in the new column resulting from aggregation over the column `am_count` grouped by `city` 
host.groupby("city")["am_count"].agg("sum").argmax()
```

Comment: Does the `Amenities` column contain a string with that weird formatting? Or does it actually contain a `set`? If it's a string, can you write code that takes one of those strings and counts the amenities?

Comment: I am not sure. Based on the output, it's a string, but I got stuck on that exact question you asked me to do ;)

Comment: I'm at wit's end. Sorry I wasn't able to help.

Comment: As a last resort, are you able to share your data source? This looks maybe like AirBnB data or something? Is there a public API or somewhere I could get this data from and mess around with tomorrow? I'm headed to bed.

Comment: You are correct it's a practice interview question from AirBnB. I found it here: https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding/9633-city-with-most-amenities?python=1.

Have a good sleep Sir! Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

```py
import functools

# Process the Amenities strings into sets of strings
host["amenities"] = host["amenities"].str.replace('["{}]', "", regex=True).str.split(",").apply(set)

# Groupby city, perform the set union to remove duplicates, and get count of unique amenities
amenities_by_city = host.groupby("city")["amenities"].apply(lambda x: len(functools.reduce(set.union, x))).reset_index()
```

Output:

```py
  city  amenities
0   LA         27
1  NYC         17
2   SF         29
```

Getting the city with the max number of amenities is achieved with

```py
city_with_most_amenities = amenities_by_city.query("amenities == amenities.max()")
```

Output:

```py
  city  amenities
2   SF         29
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238936/discussion-on-answer-by-ddejohn-find-the-city-with-highest-number-of-amenities).